# SublimeText LaTeXTools: Build doesn't render a PDF

Tags: latex, sublime-text-2, evince

I'm using the LaTeXTools plugin for SublimeText 2, and when running the build, the build system compiles the TeX and invokes Evince, but a PDF file is never rendered and thus, Evince complains, "No such file or directory".

I looked through the plugin settings (and all other auxiliary files are produced in the same directory as my TeX file) and didn't find anywhere to specify an output path, so I'm just expecting that the PDF should end up in the same directory as my input TeX file.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

I'm running SublimeText 2.0.1, 2217 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind... The build system was incorrectly informing me that there existed "no errors" in my TeX, when in fact there was one. Looking in the log revealed it. It's working just fine.

Perhaps this may serve some use to disseminate proper log information in the future.